# Changing stream source

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular I have abstract class which is responsible for query params change:

```js
@Injectable()
export abstract class PageDetailsAbstract<T> implements OnInit {
  object: string;
  id: number;
  details$: Observable<T>;

  constructor(
    protected entitiesSelectors: EntitiesSelectors) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        map(resp => +resp.id),
      )
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.id = resp;
        this.adopt();
      });
  }

  protected adopt() {
    if (this.id) {
      this.details$ = this.entitiesSelectors.details(this.object, this.id);
    }
  }
}
```

I have also concrete class for detail page:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-maile-szczegoly',
  templateUrl: './page-maile-szczegoly.component.html',
  styles: [],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PageMailsDetailComponent extends PageDetailsAbstract<Mail> {
  object = 'mails';
  // ...

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.details$
      .subscribe(data => {
        // do something with it
        // it's triggered only once
      });
  }
}
```

Problem is that `subscribe` in `ngOnInit` is triggered only once. It's because of `this.details$ = this.entitiesSelectors.details(this.object, this.id);` in parent class. Instance of `this.detials$` is destroyed and with it `subscribe` function.

How can have always the same instance of `this.details$` but always correct one with `this.entitiesSelectors.details(this.object, this.id)`?

Comment: When is `destroy$` used ?

Comment: in `ngOnDestroy`. It's just a shortcut.

Comment: Yeah well your shortcut might be the reason this doesn't work, so please provide a [mcve] of your issue

Comment: It's really not - I deleted it

Comment: Doesn't forbid you to provide a [mcve] though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `Subject` (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html)

I created a very simplified stackblitz to show how it works
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyvkpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

see the console output to verify.

here is the relevant code part (adapted to your case, not 1:1 from stackblitz)

```js
@Injectable()
export abstract class PageDetailsAbstract<T> implements OnInit {
  object: string;
  id: number;
  details$: Subject<T> = new Subject<T>();

  constructor(
    protected entitiesSelectors: EntitiesSelectors) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        map(resp => +resp.id),
      )
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.id = resp;
        this.adopt();
      });
  }

  protected adopt() {
    if (this.id) {
      this.entitiesSelectors.details(this.object, this.id).subscribe((detail: T) => {
        this.details$.next(detail);
    });
  }
}
```

personally I would restructure the code a bit.
it is a bet cleaner because you will not nest multiple calls to `subscribe` and you don't rely (at least not that much) on `this.id` which exists outside the rxjs flow.

to

```js
@Injectable()
export abstract class PageDetailsAbstract<T> implements OnInit {
  object: string;
  id: number;
  details$: Subject<T> = new Subject<T>();

  constructor(
    protected entitiesSelectors: EntitiesSelectors) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((resp: any) => {
         return this.adopt(+resp.id);
      }))
      .subscribe((detail: T) => {
        this.details$.next(detail);
      });
  }

  protected adopt(id: number): Observable<T> {
    if (this.id) {
      return this.entitiesSelectors.details(this.object, this.id);
    }
    else {
      return of(null); // or whatever is appropriate in your case (e.g. EMPTY or something)
    }
}
```

your child class would remain the same.

**why**
as for why your example didn't work:
I think it was because `details$` is a cold observable. (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html)

when you reassign `details$` you create a new observable and the previously made subscription has no meaning because it was for another observable. You would need to subscribe anew.

`Subject` is a hot observable. 
Maybe you could also use something like `publish` or `share` to transform your cold observable to a hot one.

Comment: With some adjustment it works - thanks (I choose second solution)